# Let ($\mathbb{R}^n$,*) be a division algebra over $\mathbb{R}$, $n>1$, $\Rightarrow n$ is even

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I want to prove: Let ($\mathbb{R}^n$,*) be a division algebra over $\mathbb{R}$, $n>1$, $\Rightarrow n$ is even.

I'm stuck. My thoughts are: I want to use the hairy ball theorem and I want to construct  a vector field such that the vector field vanishes nowhere: $v:S^{n-1}\to \mathbb{R}^n$, so $v$ has to be continuous and $\langle v(x),x\rangle=0$ for every $x\in S^{n-1}$ and $v(x)\in T_xS^{n-1}$, $v(x)\not= 0$ for every $x\in S^{n-1}$.If n is even, $n-1$ is odd and the hairy ball theorem tells me that i can construct v such that v vanishes nowhere.

Someone gave me the hint that i should use that $n_a: \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\},\; x\mapsto ax$ is a homeomorphism, n>1 and $a\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$,  because  $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a division algebra. My read is to use this for the construction of $v$. Furthermore i know: $ \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\} $ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-1}$ but i'm not sure if I need this. My question is: How to construct this $v$ with the properties as stated above? I'm stuck.  My only read is that v has to be something like a "multiplication-map" as my homeomorphism, but I dont know what the map $v$ has to do exactly. And if the map $v$ is constructed, what to do next? Then I'm done? I don't need to apply homology I think, is it correct? Help would be greatly appreciated. Regards

Edit: 
1)I know the definition: a "division algebra" A is a finite-dimensional algebra (wich could be non-associative) such that A is an integral domain.
2)This is a homework of a algebraic topology lecture. We talked about homology in lecture and now we talk about applications of homology. We only had the definition what a vector field is and the hairy ball theorem. I dont know Lie groups for example.

Ok my problem now is to find the inverse function of $M_a:S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1} x\mapsto \frac{a\star x}{\|a\star x\|_2}$, $a\in S^{n-1}$ as you can see in the comments below. I want to express its inverse function with the inverse function of $L_a:S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}, x\mapsto a\star x$. 
 My aim is to prove that the map $M_a$ is a diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Answer**

Here is a hint. For the two obvious cases of division algebras over $\mathbb{R}$, namely the complex numbers and the quaternions, we know that the set of unit vectors (more generally, the set of non-zero vectors) is a Lie group. Moreover, for any Lie group, we know that they are parallelizable---that is, the tangent bundle to the Lie group is trivial.

Can you use this to get the result that you're looking for?

**Expanded given more context**

(For reference, a Lie group is just a group that is also a smooth manifold. That said, I will try and extract that from the outline of a proof)

The key idea is that on your collection of non-zero vectors in your division algebra $A$ you have a translation map: that is, for each $a \in A$, you have a map $T_a : A \to A$ which is just multiplication by $a$. Moreover, you can check that this will induce an isomorphism on tangent spaces (this is important!).

So consider the tangent space to the origin $1 \in A$ (though any fixed point will do). This is a non-zero vector space, so choose a non-zero vector in this vector space.

What happens if you then look at the translates of this non-zero tangent vector across the whole collection of non-zero vectors?

Comment: It's worth noting that since you haven't specified that the division algebra is a *normed* division algebra, you have to consider the non-zero elements of your division algebra, not just $S^1$ or $S^3$, for example.

Comment: hi. thank you for the answer. Sorry, i should add some details what i had in lecture and the definition of "division algebra". Because i never heard something about Lie groups and something like that.

Comment: Interesting... a new challenge: prove this using only topology (and algebra), no mention of Lie groups.

Comment: @GEdgar - in this case, I don't think it's too hard to export the argument from any reference to Lie groups, since the key is really just that you have a method to translate non-zero vectors throughout your tangent spaces; that doesn't actually need the definition of a Lie group to do that.

Comment: Is the map $T_a$ necessarily smooth?  If not, is there still some way in which $T_a$ induces a map on tangent spaces?

Comment: It is definitely a smooth map. After all, it is just the map $f(x) = a \cdot x$...

Comment: @JasonDeVito It's smooth because multiplication is (bi)linear in its arguments and (bi)linear maps on a finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space are always smooth.

Comment: @Johannes:  Thank you!  This is not the first time I've asked and been given this (perfectly good) answer.  Hopefully, this time I'll remember it.

Comment: @Simon:  But $a\cdot x$ just indicates some random map $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying some particular algebraic condition (distribuitivity), which doesn't (a priori) take into account the topology on $\mathbb{R}$.  Johannes comment makes it clear, though.  (And now that I understand, $+1$ from me.)